# How to return the custom control's properties in UIAutomation?

Tags: c#, winforms, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I have referred the following [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747208%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article and successfully implemented the returning of the properties(UIAutomation) for default ControlTypes.

**Here is the sample code**

```
object IRawElementProviderSimple.GetPropertyValue(int propId)
{
    if (propId == AutomationElementIdentifiers.NameProperty.Id)
    {
        return "Custom list control";
    }
    else if (propId == AutomationElementIdentifiers.ControlTypeProperty.Id)
    {
        return ControlType.List.Id;  
    }
    else if (propId == AutomationElementIdentifiers.IsContentElementProperty.Id)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (propId == AutomationElementIdentifiers.IsControlElementProperty.Id)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the above code, If the property id is control type, we can return the default ControlTypes which is listed in System.Windows.Automation.ControlType.

I have referred this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671603%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to register the custom properties. Unfortunately i could not able to implement this.

But i am afraid that whether it is possible to return the properties of my custom control. Can you please suggest your ideas?

Comment: The list of ControlTypes is predefined and can't be changed.What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: My requirement is that to display my custom properties in Coded UI test builder. With above code, default properties like HelpText property,ControlName property..etc only will be displayed in Coded UI test builder. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "custom properties". The list of properties is quite fixed also. Maybe you could use AriaPropertiesProperty which is some kind of a generic property bag.

Comment: Custom properties means that my control's properties like BackColor, ForeColor..etc. i need to expose these properties in Test builder. I hope you can understand my situation

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for your update. Can you please let me know the reason?

Comment: There's no specific reason, UIAutomation doesn't not allow you to expose custom props.